# Using crosstab on a query with a composite key (multiple columns)

Tags: postgresql, crosstab, composite-key

I recently switched from SQL Server to PostgreSQL and trying to find equivalent of pivot function. I am not able to get a desired output using crosstab which I was able to achieve using SQL Server.

Sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE loc
AS
  SELECT location, sub_location, step, amount
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( 100 , '100_A', 'step_1', 2 ),
    ( 100 , '100_A', 'step_2', 7 ),
    ( 100 , '100_A', 'step_3', 6 ),
    ( 100 , '100_B', 'step_1', 5 ),
    ( 100 , '100_B', 'step_2', 8 ),
    ( 100 , '100_B', 'step_3', 9 )
  ) AS t(location, sub_location, step, amount);
```

I am trying to achieve this below result set.

```
Location    Sub_location    Step_1  Step_2  Step_3
--------    ------------    ------  ------  ------
100         100_A           2       7       6
100         100_B           5       8       9
```

I could easily achieve this is MS SQL. And my crosstab query,

```
Select * from crosstab
    (
     'select location, sub_location, step, amount from loc',
     'select distinct step from loc'
    )
    as final_result(location varchar,sub_location varchar, step_1 int, step_2 int, step_3 int);
```

I only see one row instead of two row. Anyway to overcome this limitation in postgres.

Comment: This is the first time I am posting a question, please dont mind the format.

Comment: You should flag this and ask the admins to migrate to [dba.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using ARRAY to solve the composite key problem

I think the real issue that you're having is that your `sub_location` is part of your primary identifier (name) for the purposes of cross. And, not what [crosstab calls an extra column.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html)

> The "extra" columns are expected to be the same for all rows with the same row_name value.

So in essence, composite keys forming a name must be serialized by the user. You can still make this work serializing to a SQL `ARRAY` of type `text[]`, using `ARRAY[location, sub_location]::text[]`.

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  $$ SELECT ARRAY[location, sub_location]::text[], step, amount FROM loc ORDER BY 1, 2, 3; $$,
  $$ SELECT DISTINCT step FROM loc ORDER BY 1; $$
) AS t(location text[], step_1 int, step_2 int, step_3 int );

  location   | step_1 | step_2 | step_3 
-------------+--------+--------+--------
 {100,100_A} |      2 |      7 |      6
 {100,100_B} |      5 |      8 |      9
(2 rows)
```

## Exploiting your sublocation having the actual location in it

Now, because sub-location in your specific case has data of location we can make this even shorter by switching the ordering around. I wouldn't have sub-location stored in the table with `100_`, but we can make use of that here. To be clear, this wouldn't work if `location: 100, sublocation: 'A'` which is the way I would store it.

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  $$ SELECT sub_location, location, step, amount FROM loc ORDER BY 1, 2, 3; $$,
  $$ SELECT DISTINCT step FROM loc ORDER BY 1; $$
) AS t(sub_location text, location int, step_1 int, step_2 int, step_3 int );
 sub_location | location | step_1 | step_2 | step_3 
--------------+----------+--------+--------+--------
 100_A        |      100 |      2 |      7 |      6
 100_B        |      100 |      5 |      8 |      9
(2 rows)
```

This eliminates the complexity of the call to `ARRAY` though.

## Simplifying for your use case

We can also just drop `location at this point or switch the order around in a parent query.

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  $$ SELECT sub_location, step, amount FROM loc ORDER BY 1, 2, 3; $$,
  $$ SELECT DISTINCT step FROM loc ORDER BY 1; $$
) AS t(location_full text, step_1 int, step_2 int, step_3 int );

 location_full | step_1 | step_2 | step_3 
---------------+--------+--------+--------
 100_A         |      2 |      7 |      6
 100_B         |      5 |      8 |      9
(2 rows)
```

Not sure which method above works best for you. Don't forget to `CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;` Of course, it's totally subjective whether or not this is easier than the not-crosstab'ed version.

Comment: Thank you very much @evan caroll Evan. This make sense and a good learning. I understand what you are trying to say on Sub_location. This was just a made up data to understand the concept. I've been a MS Sql developer and just entering to the world of postgresql. You might expect more questions from me in the future. :)